# Updated a stored procedure and now my refresh fields button is broken and my columns disappeared

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, parameters

I have a report that has been made in Visual Studio off of 3 stored procedures from SSRS, those stored procedures come with pre-set parameters that populate the parameter section in Visual Studio, which up until yesterday had worked perfectly well!

Yesterday our database managers renamed a View. So I went to update the stored procedure according, only fixing the one view name. And then when I went back to Visual Studio to refresh it, it gave me a text box I have never seen before and when I canceled it, it takes away my columns?

[here is the new text box when I try to refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cd7Rr.png)

I have double checked but all the parameter names remain the same as that was not part of the update.

[for example this is the procedure I am attempting to refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbFHb.png)

I have no idea what or why that box is popping up as my parameter types are set in the SSRS procedure (as varchar) and I am not passing nulls, so I ignore it and hit cancel (I have tried all sorts of variation of different combinations of clicking on it.)

But ultimately it refreshes like this and breaks my report
[As you can see no columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxy3T.png)4

I am able to <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd> and get my column list back but I am honestly baffled.

I have cross checked all parameters are spelled the same, I deleted and re attached the saved procedures and data sets, all parameter types are varchar...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get the prompt for parameters, just fill them in with anything valid so the SP can run. The values you type will not be used after this so it does not matter what they are.

SSRS is normally just trying to re-evaluate your SP. If you pass valid parameters in one of two things will happen.

1. Your SP will execute and your fields will re-appear or
2. The SP cannot get a list of fields but you will get an error message that you can then follow up.